# Prevent code execution on aplication start Android

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
 bfqs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                  if(isChecked==true){
                      String[] command = {"su", "-c", "echo \"" + "1" + "\" > " + FILE};
                        ShellCommand.run(command);
                  }
                  else{
                      String[] command = {"su", "-c", "echo \"" + "0" + "\" > " + FILE};
                    ShellCommand.run(command);
                  }
            }
          });
```

My problem is that commands inside are executed in the very first seconds when app is started. This causes majour lags.Is there any way i can prevent it?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep it from executing with a simple boolean

```
private boolean imAwake = false;

@Overwrite
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            imAwake = true;
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

And then prevent the code from running before the boolean is true:

```
 bfqs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
              if (imAwake) {
                   if(isChecked==true){
                       String[] command = {"su", "-c", "echo \"" + "1" + "\" > " + FILE};
                         ShellCommand.run(command);
                   }
                    else{
                       String[] command = {"su", "-c", "echo \"" + "0" + "\" > " + FILE};
                     ShellCommand.run(command);
                   }
              }
        }
      });
```

Edit:

Just saw your comment to the answer from William. As I understand it OnCheckedChangeListener is then called without any interaction when app is startet. And that is unwanted behaviour, right?

I believe OnCheckedChangeListener is called upon creation of your app to set the current value, so what I think you need to do is save the last value so that you not only check for true/false, but also check if the value is set for the first time (first ever start of the app) and if it is set to the previously saved value. Both instances where you do not want any code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer object.

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}, 1000); // 1sec
```

Comment: I want to prevent it from execution, not to delay it.It only needs to execute the code when i check it, not wehn i start the app.